# UFW unable to verfy iptables version, despite being installed

Tags: linux, networking, server, firewall, ufw

Hello I'm setting up a server to use openvpn with, to avoid the (Code=111) error I need to set a few rules to ufw. However I get the following Error with ufw...

```
user@debian:~$ sudo ufw enable
ERROR: Couldn't determine iptables version
```

the server is running debian 11
linux kernel 6.1.8

Thanks for the help in advance

I tried restarting but it did not work.
many guides don't seem to touch on this issue also.

here is some details about the server

the server is running debian 11
linux kernel 6.1.8

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100598/ufw-and-iptables-on-buster

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. You may post your question to other sites like https://superuser.com